# Recreate Activity from Activity which called from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have 2 activities. In first activity I registered BroadCastReceiver to listen network changes. In onReceive method I start second activity. And I want to recreate first activity when i click button in second activity. How can i do it?

Comment: You need to register another `broadcastReceiver` which will handle recreation of an activity. Broadcast will be sent from second activity.

Comment: @PareshP. how can I determinate which activity send broadcast?

Comment: you can add some extras into data to determine activity

Comment: @РасулA-ев as Ragahv said, You can put Boolean which will make sure that broadcast is coming from particular activity.

Comment: @PareshP. Well, I have the BaseActivity from which all activities extend. So what can i do in this case>?

Comment: You can register the broadcast receiver individually in the Activity.

Comment: I might be missing some context, but what is the problem if you simply create intent and call `startActivity` method in your second activity?